# Is there a way to create a 3d plot with contours beneath the plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to create a 3d plot in `R` that has contours beneath the plot like so? If not, is there a way to take my existing contour plot and put it on top of the 3d persp plot?

[image]

I have been able to make a 3d plot, and a contour plot of the function and constraint, but have not been able to combine the two. Here is my `R` code:

```
obj = function(x1,x2){
  value = -(cos((x1-.1)*x2))^2 - x1*sin(3*x1+x2)
  return(value)
}

con1 = function(x1,x2){
  t = atan2(x1,x2)
  value = x1^2 + x2^2 -((2*cos(t)-1/2*cos(2*t)-1/4*cos(3*t)-1/8*cos(4*t))^2) - ((2*sin(t))^2)
  return(value)
}


x1 = seq(-2.25,2.5,.015)
x2 = seq(-2.5,1.75,.015)

out = outer(x1,x2,obj)

infeasible = ifelse(c(outer(x1,x2,con1)<=0),1,0)
image(x1,x2,out,xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]),main="Modified Townsend Problem")

X = cbind(expand.grid(x1,x2),infeasible)
points(X[X[,3]==0,1],X[X[,3]==0,2],pch=19,col="lightgrey")

persp(x1,x2,out,phi=35,col="lightgrey")
```

Any suggestions or packages that do it are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon this is doable via `?contourLines` and some transformation of your points:

```
p <- persp(x1, x2, out, phi=35, col="#00000000", border=NA, box=FALSE)
cl <- contourLines(x1, x2, replace(out, outer(x1,x2,con1) > 0, NA))
levs <- factor(sapply(cl, `[[`, "level"))
Map(
  function(cl,col) lines(trans3d(cl$x, cl$y, min(out), pmat=p), col=col),
  cl,
  hcl.colors(nlevels(levs), "YlOrRd", rev = TRUE)[levs]
)
par(new=TRUE)
persp(x1, x2, out, phi=35, col="lightgrey")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is there a way to add the same colors that the image() function would produce

Comment: @JohnSmith - possibly, each of the `cl` (`contourLines`) list parts has a `$level` component which you could map to a colour.

Comment: And I guess I would also need the constrained version.

Comment: @JohnSmith - see the updated version which now has the colours. The constraining i'm not sure how to do.

Comment: To do the constraining, you just need to add `out[which(outer(x1,x2,con1)>0)]=NA`

Comment: @JohnSmith - constraining added now to give exactly what you wanted.