# "contours" is not a graphical parameter when using persp() in rsm package

Tags: r, contour, rsm

I'm trying to implement a 3D plot in R using the `rsm` package's `persp()` function. I'd like to add contour lines to the base of the plot, for example like here: [Draw a line after persp using rsm in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794011/draw-a-line-after-persp-using-rsm-in-r)

The `rsm` documentation says this should be possible:

> In persp, contour lines may be added via the contours argument. It may be a boolean or character
> value, or a list. If boolean and TRUE, default black contour lines are added to the bottom surface
> of the box

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsm/rsm.pdf

When I do this, I get a warning and no contours, although the 3D plot generates just fine: `"Warning message: In persp.default(a, t, q, contours = ("top") : "contours" is not a graphical parameter`

I was able to get this pattern working using code here: [Is there a way to create a 3d plot with contours beneath the plot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646886/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-3d-plot-with-contours-beneath-the-plot-in-r)

But it would be nice to know why the `rsm` package doesn't (appear to) work as advertised, unless I'm doing something wrong?

Here is my MWE:

```
library(rsm)

surface <- function(a, t){
  q <- (4*40)/(4*a^2 + 4*a*t^2 + t^4 + 4*40)
}

a <- seq(.00001, 5, length= 20)
t <- seq(.00001, 5, length= 20)
q <- outer(a, t, surface)

persp(a, t, q,
      contours=("top"))

persp(a, t, q,
      contours=T)
```

Comment: In `rsm`, `persp()` is actually `persp.lm()`, and its first two arguments are a lm object and a formula. Because you are passing vectors to `persp()`, you are actually calling `graphics::persp()`, which does not have a `contours` argument. Hence the warning. Have a look at `?rsm::persp.lm` for more information.

Comment: That's right. Just to emphasize this point, you can't use contour.lm to do contours of data. You have to fit a model; then you see contours of the fitted model, not of the raw data. Those can be quite different.